# Configuring Certificates in Server

Tags: java, web-services, certificate, jrockit

I am very new to webservice and configuring certificates. I have roughly gone through PKI concepts. Below are come basic questions I have

1) I have certain certificates which i use in my code to Sign the XML elements,
What is the need to add these certificates to  in the cacerts file under lib/Security of JRE
2) what is the use of this cacerts file.

I use weblogic server with jockrit jre

Do let me know , if there are some sites to learn the above concepts

Comment: Hi yeshwanth, SO avoids questions about recommendations or opinions of tools or technologies. I answered your specific doubts

Answer (score 0):

> 2) what is the use of this cacerts file.

cacerts is the default trust store of your JRE. It contains the root certificate of Certification Service Providers that JRE manufacturer considers to be trusted. Cacerts is checked by default TrustManager to verify if a certificate has been issued by some of this CSP's, for example when you invokes a third party service using SSL/TLS, the server certificate is validated

> 1) I have certain certificates which i use in my code to Sign the XML elements

You do not need to add anything to cacerts. But if you use a self-signed certificate you should provide the public part of your certificate to the receivers in order they can verify the signature.